# In yesod (haskell), how do I load a plain html-formatted file (not a hamlet) as a widget?

Tags: haskell, yesod, shakespeare-text

How do I load a plain html-formatted file (not a hamlet-formatted file) as a widget? In other words I'm looking for the html equivalent of:

```
toWidget $(whamletFile "test.hamlet")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you use `sendFile` in your handler function ([see its definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-0.4.1/docs/Yesod-Handler.html#v:sendFile))

The first argument is the Mime Type while the second is the file path.

For example, you could code something like:

```
getMyFileR :: Handler ()
getMyFileR = sendFile "text/html" "myfile.html"
```

Here’s Another example. Say I have the following model:

```
Resource
    filename    FilePath
    mimetype    ContentType

    deriving    Typeable
```

The handler might look like:

```
resourceDirectory :: FilePath
resourceDirectory = "resource"

getResourceGetR :: ResourceId -> Handler ()
getResourceGetR resourceId = do
    resource <- runDB $ get404 resourceId

    sendFile (resourceMimetype resource)
             (resourceDirectory </> unpack (resourceFilename resource))
```

**Edit 2015-06-05**

`sendFile` operates at a low level while `addScript` or `$(widgetFile …)` operates at a higher level.

`$(widgetFile …)` uses TemplateHaskell to convert your Hamlet/Cassius/Lucius/Julius templates into actual Haskell source code before your project is compiled. The same applies similarly to `[hamlet|…|]`.

`addScript`works with a `Route` while `sendFile` works with a `FilePath`. This means `addScript` will be able to detect missing files at compile time. `sendFile` will detect missing files at runtime.

There are some tools to convert Html to Hamlet:

- [a one line script](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Hamlet) (which works well for simple Html),
- [html2hamlet](https://github.com/meteficha/html2hamlet).

An equivalent of `addScript` for Html files does not make sense: `addScript` will generate a `script` tag to tell the browser to download an external resource. This does not apply to an Html file.

Comment: I'm still new to this, but isn't the syntax I used shorthand for implicitly referencing a file without setting up a resource explicitly? It seems to work for hamlet files. Regardless, once set up the resource handler, julius has the `addScript` that can be invoked on the resource to load a named external julius resource. What's the equivalent to `addScript` for a plain html resource?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Import
import Text.Blaze.Html       (preEscapedToHtml)
import Text.Shakespeare.Text (stextFile)

myWidget :: Widget
myWidget = toWidget . preEscapedToHtml $ $(stextFile "templates/some-file.html")
```